# extjs treestore with proxy type of rest appending -1 to model name

Tags: extjs

Having a peculiar problem with TreeStore where the rest type treestore adds -1 to name of model which breaks my backend routes.
TreeStore is defined as

```
   Ext.define('Gateway.store.Company', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    model: 'Gateway.model.Company',


    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url:  'http://gateway-email-mock/',
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        }
       }
});
```

where company model is defined as

```
Ext.define('Gateway.model.Company', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'id',   type: 'int'    },
        {name: 'name', type: 'string' }
    ]
});
```

The view interested in the store is

```
Ext.define('Gateway.view.company.Company', {
    extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
    alias:  'widget.company-list',
    store: 'Gateway.store.Company',
    rootVisible: false
});
```

When loading the widget the store creates URL

```
http://gateway-email-mock/Gateway.model.Company-1
```

How does -1 get there after the model name? I do not suppose this is intentional?

Thank you for any tips.

Comment: Another suggestion. The store property of a `tree.Panel` should be an instance of a store, not a string. When you use a string, it magically creates a store and registers it with the StoreManager and uses that.

Comment: It doesn't add "-1", it adds "Gateway.model.Company-1", which is probably the internal id of a record. Probably the tree store trying to load its root node or something like that. Not enough code, can't say.

Comment: @rixo I didn't think of a tree store trying to load a single root node. That makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @rixo thats all the code I have for it so far. Suggestion makes sense, but isn't rest convention suppose to do Gateway.model.Company/1 if its trying to load by ID?

Comment: @JuanMendes makes sense if ExtJS wants to add another model with the same name. Trying to see how to add model instance as opposed to name. According to the docs "model: Name of the Model associated with this store." so I am not seeing yet how to pass an existing instance of model. Also, is really an instance that needs to be passed since new Company obj is created per record?

Comment: I said the `store` property, not the `model` property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rixo is correct, that is the tree store trying to load its root node. The default id generator generates its ID in the following way

```
idgen: {
    isGenerator: true,
    type: 'default',

    generate: function () {
        return null;
    },
    getRecId: function (rec) {
        return rec.modelName + '-' + rec.internalId;
    }
}
```

Which means your root record is  `rec.modelName + '-' + rec.internalId`, which is exactly the request that is being made: `http://gateway-email-mock/Gateway.model.Company-1`

The solution is to make sure you create a root node with an ID, so that the tree's store will make a request for the correct ID , right it's generating the root node for you and giving it an automatic ID. See http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/source/TreeStore.html#Ext-data-TreeStore-method-load and http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.TreeStore-cfg-root

Comment: that makes sense and i will make adjustment. However, why does it not follow REST rules and do Gateway.model.Company/1 ?
Should I fix this by creating root node with an ID or configure rest proxy to properly ask for the model with ID?

Comment: @alex-tech There is no REST rule that a generated id would be 1. The REST rule is to append the ID to the URL and that's what it did (by creating an ID of `Gateway.model.Company-1` for you, I pointed you to the code that does that), and you can also customize it http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-cfg-idgen. However, you don't need id generation if you specify the id as I've already told you. Just specify your root node with id=1 and it will look for `Gateway.model.Company/1`

Comment: that worked. Added defaultRootID: 1 to the store which generates company/1